# Removing left arrow from the actionbar in android?

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I want to remove the left arrow from the action bar and only icon and title needed.

My code:

```
getSupportActionBar().setIcon(R.drawable.logo);
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(true);
getSupportActionBar().setTitle(R.string.dashboardtitle);
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(false);
```

But this doesn't remove the left arrow . Any help!!

Comment: I would have expected `setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(false)` to do it. Are you doing anything related to the action bar in a custom theme?

Comment: No just i want to remove that left arrow from the action bar

Comment: What is the version of Android SDK you run it?

Comment: android 4.2.2 version

Comment: Do you use ActionBar sherlock or it's native android ActionBar?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

According to specification [**android specification**](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html):
To enable the icon for up navigation (which displays the "up" indicator next to the icon), call setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(**true**) on your ActionBar:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
    actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    ...
}
```

So you should set **actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(false);**

**UPDATE:**
I test next code with ActionBar sherlock and it's work. There is no back arrow:

```
getSupportActionBar().setIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(true);
getSupportActionBar().setTitle(R.string.about_event_location);
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(false);
```

Comment: still there is small black space left

Answer (score 22):

You need to add this to your actionBar theme. You can replace arrow image with your own image which can be transparent

```
<item name="android:homeAsUpIndicator">@drawable/action_arrow</item>
```

Comment: This worked!  I had to set the new drawable to a transparent image of some width, since using `@android:color/transparent` does not include any padding to the left of the app's icon.

Comment: It's possible to use @null to avoid create a transparent image resource.

<item name="android:homeAsUpIndicator">@null</item>

Answer (score 3):

```
getActionBar().setHomeAsUpIndicator(R.drawable.action_arrow);
```

Where action_arrow is a 25x10px transparent png. 
Same code for sherlock would be:

```
getSupportActionBar().setHomeAsUpIndicator(R.drawable.action_arrow);
```

Answer (score 1):

@vivek: works great. I do not recommend to use @android:color/transparent as Tim Cooper said, because the Title is aligned to the left. So a empty image is better

Comment: This looks more like an comment than an answer.

Answer (score 0):

In AndroidManifest.xml

remove the below code, which will remove back button from your ActionBar

```
android:parentActivityName=".Main.MainActivity">
<meta-data
android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
android:value=".Main.MainActivity" />
```

Just keep it like below:

```
<activity
android:name=".YourActivity"
android:label="@string/your_activity_label">
</activity>
```

Comment: I ran into the ugly back arrow issue precisely because I had to add the android:parentActivityName attribute in order to build a proper back stack! Your solution can also break the desired behavior of the system's back button.