# How to set a custom back button in ActionBar?

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I am creating an ActionBar (SupportActionBar, more precisely) this way:

```
android.support.v7.app.ActionBar actionBar=getSupportActionBar();
    actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_STANDARD);
    actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(true);
    actionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
    actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    //actionBar.setDisplayOptions(actionBar.setDisplayOptions(ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_HOME | ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_TITLE););
    actionBar.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_drawer);
    actionBar.setTitle(mTitle);
```

This way, I get a button in my action bar which, once clicked, does what I want it to do. But, it displays an arrow pointing to the left. I would like to display another drawable, so I uncomment the setDisplayOptions line, and the icon I want is displayed. But, the button is no longer clickable.

How could I set my drawable to the button, and maintaining it clickable?

Comment: try this link,
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16771532/removing-left-arrow-from-the-actionbar-in-android?rq=1

Comment: I haven't seen that answer before, it helped me. Thank you!

Comment: happy coding Fustigader.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `setHomeAsUpIndicator()` method instead

```
actionBar.setHomeAsUpIndicator(R.drawable.ic_drawer);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to back arrow button, just use below code:

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

    val ab = actionBar
    ab?.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true)
    getSupportActionBar()?.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
}

override fun onOptionsItemSelected(item: MenuItem?): Boolean {
   finish()
   return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item)
}
```